# Does System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol use Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sockets, asmx

I am currently developing an App that talks to a Web Service via:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
```

I am also using MobileIron AppTunnel to make a connection to my asmx Web Service.

MobileIron AppTunnel doesn't support the use of Sockets. I am trying to work out if my current connection is using Sockets.

If it is, how else can I connect to my Web Service?

Comment: How can something that makes http requests not use sockets?

Comment: @Evk this is where I show my ignorance. Is it true then that all HTTP requests are done using Sockets? If so, is it possible to call a ASMX service without using Sockets?

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Socket is low-level construct which is used (among other things) to establish TCP connection. So to me, doing http request "without using sockets" does not make much sense. Maybe you can clarify what you mean (and also what does it mean "MobileIron AppTunnel doesn't support the use of Sockets", also what that AppTunel is).

Comment: @Evk, MobileIron is a security container installed on our corporate devices. From their website: "AppTunnel provides granular, app-by-app session security to connect each app container to the corporate network."

We are developing an app and want it to talk to a service on our network. The response I have been given from MobileIron when this didn't work was "apps using sockets for networking are incompatible with appTunnel". 

I don't know how else I can connect to my service.

Comment: In application in question mobile one or desktop?

Comment: @Evk it's a Mobile App on iOS using Xamarin (ie Mono/.NET).

Comment: I guess what they mean is they cannot intercept network communications made through raw sockets (and they need to do it to route them through their secure tunnel), so you have to use api that supports that. I'd suggest to ask them which api is compatible in your specific case (ios xamarin app). Maybe for example xamarin's `ModernHttpClient` will do. There is high chance that you will have to make soap requests yourself (for example if it will turn out that only supported api is something like that ModernHttpClient).

Comment: @Evk thanks for your help. If want to put an Answer that the premise of the question is slightly off and explain it like you have here I'd gladly mark it as accepted.